# pickerInput not working properly with grid_template from shiny.semantic

Tags: r, shiny, semantic-ui

I need help using shiny.semantic package with pickerInput. My intention is to make my shiny app responsive and display well both on desktop and mobile. It displays well on both device except the pickerInput. Whenever the pickerInput is clicked to display its items, it does not collapse when clicked again. See image below
[image]

I need it to collapse back normally as it behaves when I am not using the **shiny.semantic package's grid_template**. Below is my script

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shiny.semantic)
  library(leaflet)
  library(shinyWidgets)
  library(shinyjs)
  library(shinycssloaders)
  library(htmlwidgets)
  library(hrbrthemes)
  
  # Interactive Visualizations
  library(plotly)
  library(ggtext)
  
  # Core packages
  library(tidyverse)
  
  library(DBI)
  #library(RMySQL)
  library(RMariaDB)
  library(odbc)
  library(sp)
  years_vector <- c("2020", "2021")
  
  months_vector <-
    c(
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    )
  
  
  myGridTemplate <- grid_template(
    default = list(areas = rbind(
      c(
        "search_info1",
        "search_info2",
        "search_info3"
      )),
    mobile = list(
      areas = rbind(
        "search_info1",
        "search_info2",
        "search_info3"
      ),
      rows_height = c(
        "100px",
        "100px",
        "100px"
      ),
      cols_width = c("100%")
    )))
  
  #display_grid(myGridTemplate)
  ui <- semanticPage(
    grid(
      myGridTemplate,
      search_info1 = shiny::column(
        id = "column_selector_year",
        width = 2,
        offset = 3,
        shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
          inputId  = "picker_year",
          label    = h5("Select Year "),
          choices  = c("2020", "2021"),
          selected = "2020",
          multiple = FALSE,
          options  = list(
            `actions-box` = FALSE,
            size = 2,
            `selected-text-format` = "count > 2"
          )
        )
      ),
      search_info2 = shiny::column(
        id = "column_selector_month",
        2,
        shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
          inputId  = "picker_month",
          label    = h5("Select Month"),
          choices  = c(
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
          ),
          selected = c(
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
          ),
          multiple = TRUE,
          
          options  = list(
            `actions-box` = TRUE,
            size = 4,
            `selected-text-format` = "count > 2"
          )
        )
      ),
      search_info3 = column(
        id = "column_selector4",
        2,
        br(),
        br(),
        actionButton(inputId = "apply", label = "Update")
      )
    
  ))
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    
  }
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I get the pickerInput to collapse normally when clicked again as it does using shiny?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to some of the CSS classes clashing between the `{shiny}` Bootstrap UI framework `{shiny.semantic}` Semantic UI, you'll experience some unexpected behaviour with some of the extension packages.

To write something similar using `{shiny.semantic}`, you can use `dropdown_input` and adding in a bit of JS. I can't find an easy way of auto selecting everything within the dropdown with a button, but to remove all options in one easy click I've added the "clearable" class.

##### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.semantic)

myGridTemplate <- shiny.semantic::grid_template(
  default = list(
    areas = rbind(
      c(
        "search_info1",
        "search_info2",
        "search_info3"
      )
    ),
    mobile = list(
      areas = rbind(
        "search_info1",
        "search_info2",
        "search_info3"
      ),
      rows_height = c(
        "100px",
        "100px",
        "100px"
      ),
      cols_width = "100%"
    )
  )
)

ui <- shiny.semantic::semanticPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "updateMonthInput.js")
  ),

  shiny.semantic::grid(
    myGridTemplate,
    search_info1 = shiny.semantic::form(
      shiny.semantic::field(
        tags$label("Select Year"),
        shiny.semantic::dropdown_input(
          input_id = "picker_year",
          c(2020, 2021)
        )
      )
    ),
    search_info2 = shiny.semantic::form(
      shiny.semantic::field(
        tags$label("Select Month"),
        shiny.semantic::dropdown_input(
          input_id = "picker_month",
          type = "multiple clearable selection",
          month.name, value = month.name
        )
      )
    ),
    search_info3 = div(
      id = "column_selector4",
      tags$br(),
      shiny.semantic::actionButton(
        inputId = "apply",
        label = "Update"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

##### www/updateMonthInput.js

```js
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {
  var picker_month_values = $('#picker_month').dropdown('get value').split(',');
  $('#picker_month').dropdown('clear');
  $('#picker_month').dropdown({useLabels: false});
  $('#picker_month').dropdown('set exactly', picker_month_values);
});
```

The reason for doing this once shiny is connected is to make sure the "X selected" appears correctly. The dropdown needs to be temporarily cleared to prevent the dropdown to show all of the months individually.

[image: Year and month dropdowns using Fomantic UI dropdown with button]

##### Extra

I've noticed that you want this to appear as a single column when in mobile mode. I'd recommend using `shiny.semantic::form` as this produces this in a simple way. I've rewritten the grid above to show you how it would look like:

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.semantic)

ui <- shiny.semantic::semanticPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "updateInput.js")
  ),
  
  shiny.semantic::form(
    shiny.semantic::fields(
      class = "three",
      shiny.semantic::field(
        tags$label("Select Year"),
        shiny.semantic::dropdown_input(
          input_id = "picker_year",
          c(2020, 2021)
        )
      ),
      shiny.semantic::field(
        tags$label("Select Month"),
        shiny.semantic::dropdown_input(
          input_id = "picker_month",
          type = "multiple clearable selection",
          month.name, value = month.name
        )
      ),
      shiny.semantic::field(
        id = "column_selector4",
        tags$br(),
        shiny.semantic::actionButton(
          inputId = "apply",
          label = "Update"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

###### Desktop

[image: year and month dropdowns using Fomantic UI Form]

###### Mobile

[image: stacked year and month dropdowns using Fomantic UI Form in mobile mode]

Comment: Thank you Ashley